# Snowflake COPY: how to insert load time automatically when I use the MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME option

Tags: copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use Snowflake copy with MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME option. We use MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME because we have a very long and evolving list of column names. Is there a way to include a LOAD_TIME field with the current timestamp at the time of loading (or copy compilation)?

I tried to add a
`LOAD_TIME timestamp default current_timestamp()` 
in the destination table, but I got NULL value after copy because of the MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is default behaviour, `COPY` into inserts NULL into other columns and does not allow to use transformation syntax, thus NULL even with default defined.

```
COPY INTO t
FROM (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS LOAD_TIME, ...
      FROM stage)
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE;
-- SQL compilation error: match_by_column_name is not supported with copy transform
```

**[COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html)**:

> ```
> MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_SENSITIVE | CASE_INSENSITIVE | NONE
> ```
>
> ...
> Note
>
> - If additional non-matching columns are present in the target table, **the COPY operation inserts NULL values into these columns.** These columns must support NULL values.
> - The COPY statement does not allow specifying a query to further transform the data during the load **(i.e. COPY transformation)**.

Comment: A nice possiblity to solve it would be support of "Column DEFAULT value on explicit NULL" - the idea was added: https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas?t=1644086987475